# Overload reference conversions

Tags: c++, reference, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

The following class seems to [compile](http://ideone.com/X8020), but the conversion operators are never called:

```
class A
{
public:
  operator A() const { std::cout << "A() called" << std::endl; return *this; }
  operator A&() { std::cout << "A&() called" << std::endl; return *this; }
  operator const A&() const { std::cout << "const A&() called" << std::endl; return *this; }
};
```

Is a function specifying a conversion to a reference to itself simply ignored?

Comment: I'm sure someone will quote the standard, but in the meantime I'll state the obvious: this doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quote from 12.3.2

`A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it)`

Also, using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi` on gcc gave me: `warning: this statement has no effect` for the static cast. (Also, try [clang online](http://llvm.org/demo/) it will give you some nice compiler error messages).